# Unable to keep other widgets fixed and Listview.builder scroll in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to keep the container above my list view builder fixed and the list view to scroll. but when I implement the following code it shows renderflex overflow issue.

Code:

```
List<String> companynames = [
    'Delloite',
    'Google',
    'Amazon',
    'Apple',
    'Tata',
    'Wipro',
    'Tesla',
    'Cupid',
    'Pfizer',
    'Mango',
    'Reliance',
    'Titan',
    'Toyota',
    'Maruti',
    'Volkswagen',
    'Suzuki'
  ];
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        //mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: [
          Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                color: kbluePrimaryColor,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 20.0,
                    right: 20.0,
                    top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.12,
                  ),
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      //physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      itemCount: companynames.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Card(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius:
                                  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15))),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Text(
                              companynames[index],
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: kblackPrimaryColor,
                                fontSize:
                                    MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.06,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      }),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

I want the blue container to be fixed and the list view's first item to be half overlapping the blue container and scrollable. Can someone please tell how to do this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try with this

```
 List<String> companynames = [
    'Delloite',
    'Google',
    'Amazon',
    'Apple',
    'Tata',
    'Wipro',
    'Tesla',
    'Cupid',
    'Pfizer',
    'Mango',
    'Reliance',
    'Titan',
    'Toyota',
    'Maruti',
    'Volkswagen',
    'Suzuki'
  ];
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            color: Colors.green,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              left: 20.0,
              right: 20.0,
              top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.12,
            ),
            child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                //physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: companynames.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Card(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius:
                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15))),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        companynames[index],
                        style: TextStyle(
                          //  color: kblackPrimaryColor,
                          fontSize:
                          MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.06,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Output:

[image]